# sqlalchemy ORM call fails with TypeError: expected bytes, str found

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, pg8000

I am making the following (relatively) simple call in a bit of code I have written:

```
pickups = session.query(Pickup).filter(Pickup.firebase_run_id == run_id).all()
```

I have two sets of integration tests over this code, one that runs locally and uses `psycops2` and TLS, and one that runs in a GCP dev environment (a GCP cloud function) and uses `pg8000` and a UNIX socket (GCP mandates (?) that cloud functions connect to Cloud SQL over a UNIX socket -- see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#public-ip-default)). The local integration tests run fine. However, the dev tests reliably fail with the following error:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/user_code/main.py", line 245, in GET_run
        response = run_get(run_id)
      File "/user_code/rubbish_geo_client/ops.py", line 686, in run_get
        pickups = session.query(Pickup).filter(Pickup.firebase_run_id == run_id).all()
      File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3319, in all
        return list(self)
      File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3481, in __iter__
        return self._execute_and_instances(context)
      File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3503, in _execute_and_instances
        querycontext, self._connection_from_session, close_with_result=True
    TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

This specific function call is actually just one example of such a failure; all of my database calls fail with the same `_execute_and_instances` error!

Perhaps someone has an insight into what a workaround for this might be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pg8000` had a longstanding bug in its implementation that the `sqlalchemy` driver just patched over. The new `pg8000` maintainer recently introduced a patch for this issue, and released a new version of `pg8000` that includes the fix. This unfortunately had the side-effect of breaking the `sqlalchemy` workaround.

Until `sqlalchemy` changes its driver to respect this patch, for now the best solution is to downgrade `pg8000` from 1.16.6 to 1.16.5 or lower.

You can do so using `pip install pg8000<=1.16.5`.

For reference, refer to the following conversations: [GH#commitcomment-43174891](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/commit/3a2e7439ae3613367ec231218d7e0f541466d1e5#commitcomment-43174891), [GH#53](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/issues/53).

Answer (score 0):

pg8000 [is supported](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.pg8000) in SQLAlchemy 1.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative work around

```
pool.dialect.description_encoding = None
```

Sources:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5645#issuecomment-707879323
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/main.py